# How do I get past authentication for setting local host name via kubespray?

Tags: kubernetes, ssh, ansible, kubespray

Hi i keep getting this error when using ansible via kubespray and I am wondering how to over come it

```
TASK [bootstrap-os : Assign inventory name to unconfigured hostnames (non-CoreOS, non-Flatcar, Suse and ClearLinux)] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/dc/xcp-projects/kubespray/roles/bootstrap-os/tasks/main.yml:50

<192.168.10.55> (1, b'\x1b[1;31m==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.hostname1.set-hostname ===\r\n\x1b[0mAuthentication is required to set the local host name.\r\nMultiple identities can be used for authentication:\r\n 1.  test\r\n 2.  provision\r\n 3.  dc\r\nChoose identity to authenticate as (1-3): \r\n{"msg": "Command failed rc=1, out=, err=\\u001b[0;1;31mCould not set property: Connection timed out\\u001b[0m\\n", "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"name": "node3", "use": null}}}\r\n', b'Shared connection to 192.168.10.55 closed.\r\n')
<192.168.10.55> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to 192.168.10.55 closed.
<192.168.10.55> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: provision
<192.168.10.55> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/home/dc/.ssh/xcp_server_k8s_nodes/xcp-k8s-provision-key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="provision"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ControlPath=/home/dc/.ansible/cp/c6d70a0b7d 192.168.10.55 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /home/provision/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1614373378.5434802-17760837116436/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.10.56> (0, b'', b'')
fatal: [node2]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "name": "node2",
            "use": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "Command failed rc=1, out=, err=\u001b[0;1;31mCould not set property: Method call timed out\u001b[0m\n"
}
```

my inventory file is as follows

```
all:
  hosts:
    node1:
      ansible_host: 192.168.10.54
      ip: 192.168.10.54
      access_ip: 192.168.10.54
    node2:
      ansible_host: 192.168.10.56
      ip: 192.168.10.56
      access_ip: 192.168.10.56
    node3:
      ansible_host: 192.168.10.55
      ip: 192.168.10.55
      access_ip: 192.168.10.55
  children:
    kube-master:
      hosts:
        node1:
        node2:
    kube-node:
      hosts:
        node1:
        node2:
        node3:
    etcd:
      hosts:
        node1:
        node2:
        node3:
    k8s-cluster:
      children:
        kube-master:
        kube-node:
    calico-rr:
      hosts: {}
```

I also have a file which provision the users in the following manner

```
- name: Add a new user named provision
  user:
    name: provision
    create_home: true
    shell: /bin/bash
    password: "{{ provision_password }}"
    groups: sudo
    append: yes

- name: Add a new user named dc
  user:
    name: dc
    create_home: true
    shell: /bin/bash
    password: "{{ provision_password }}"
    groups: sudo
    append: yes

- name: Add provision user to the sudoers
  copy:
    dest: "/etc/sudoers.d/provision"
    content: "provision  ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: ALL"

- name: Add provision user to the sudoers
  copy:
    dest: "/etc/sudoers.d/dc"
    content: "dc  ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: ALL"


- name: Disable Root Login
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^PermitRootLogin'
    line: "PermitRootLogin no"
    state: present
    backup: yes

  notify:
    - Restart ssh
```

I have run the ansible command in the following manner

```
ansible-playbook -i kubespray/inventory/mycluster/hosts.yaml --user="provision"  --ssh-extra-args="-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no" --key-file "/home/dc/.ssh/xcp_server_k8s_nodes/xcp-k8s-provision-key" kubespray/cluster.yml -vvv
```

as well as

```
ansible-playbook -i kubespray/inventory/mycluster/hosts.yaml --user="provision"  --ssh-extra-args="-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no" --key-file "/home/dc/.ssh/xcp_server_k8s_nodes/xcp-k8s-provision-key" --become-user="provision" kubespray/cluster.yml -vv
```

both yield the same error an interestingly escalation seems to succeed on earlier points

after reading this article
https://askubuntu.com/questions/542397/change-default-user-for-authentication
I have decided to add the users to the sudo group but the error still persists

looking into the main.yaml file position suggested by the error it seems to be this code possibly causing issues?

```
# Workaround for https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/42726
# (1/3)
- name: Gather host facts to get ansible_os_family
  setup:
    gather_subset: '!all'
    filter: ansible_*

- name: Assign inventory name to unconfigured hostnames (non-CoreOS, non-Flatcar, Suse and ClearLinux)
  hostname:
    name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  when:
    - override_system_hostname
    - ansible_os_family not in ['Suse', 'Flatcar Container Linux by Kinvolk', 'ClearLinux'] and not is_fedora_coreos
```

The OS'es of the hosts are ubuntu 20.04.02 server
is there anything more I can do?

Comment: It sure does look like you have a custom sudo process, which will require some special handling on your part. Also, be aware that (AFAIK) merely specifying `--become-user` does not automatically engage `--become` (you may already have `become: yes` in your playbook, but we can't guess that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Kubespray documentation:

```sh
# Deploy Kubespray with Ansible Playbook - run the playbook as root
# The option `--become` is required, as for example writing SSL keys in /etc/,
# installing packages and interacting with various systemd daemons.
# Without --become the playbook will fail to run!
ansible-playbook -i inventory/mycluster/hosts.yaml  --become --become-user=root cluster.yml
```

As stated, the `--become` is mandatory, it allows to do privilege escalation for most of the system modifications (like setting the hostname) that Kubespray performs.

With `--user=provision` you're just setting the SSH user, but it will need privilege escalation anyway.
With `--become-user=provision` you're just saying that privilege escalation will escalade to 'provision' user (but you would need `--become` to do the privilege escalation).
In both cases, unless 'provision' user has root permissions (not sure putting it in `root` group is enough), it won't be enough.

For the user 'provision' to be enough, you need to make sure that it can perform a `hostnamectl <some-new-host>` without being asked for authentication.

Comment: ah ok thanks @zigarn, so if I add become will privilege escalation persists as provision rather than root?

Comment: `--become` just add `sudo` when executing ansible modules (`sudo -u xxx` if `--become-user=xxx`) while connecting as `--user yyy`. Not sure to understand your question.